# Rails validation precedence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model Customer payment as bellow  ,

```
class Customerpayment < ActiveRecord::Base
#validation
  validates :amount ,   numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :amount ,   presence: true
  validates :date   ,   presence: true


  validates_each :amount do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add(attr, I18n.t(:invalid_paid)) if !valid_paid_amount(record , value) 
  end
end
```

- the problem is the validation  `validates_each :amount` works before `validates :amount ,     presence: true` and I want the last to work first , any help please to get `validation validates :amount ,     presence: true` work first

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails does all the validations you specify, even if one fails. So, changing the order won't effect your code here.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966055/controlling-the-order-of-rails-validations) for details