# Does rails custom validation fail on return true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966318/1793442), the custom validation fails when the method `return true`.

I want to know if this is mentioned in official docs? The rails guide only mention `errors.add` as a way to trigger custom validation method to fail.

Comment: I think you are wrong. The returned value means nothing in case of custom validation. Can you show an example that confirms your statement ?

Comment: How would you interpret the linked answer? How does the custom validation method fail in that example?

Comment: The linked answer has nothing to do with your problem.  In the example `return` means that you exit the method, the returned value is nil, no errors are added, the validation succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how you are using your custom validations.

If you are using Active Record Callbacks, i.e. `before_save` or `before_validation`, if you `return false` from any of these, your validation will FAIL and the record will not be saved:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-before_validation-2A+returning+statements

However if you are using a custom validator such as mentioned here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations the return value is not significant (It is not mentioned in the docs, as you say), what matters is if you add to the errors array.

Comment: Just note that from Rails 5 onwards, the `return true` method does not work, you'll need to `throw :abort` instead. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Comment: Please mark this solution as not correct as with rails > 5 it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As of rails-5.0 returning `false` in a `before_*` chain will not fail the validation. The only way to halt the chain is to `throw :abort`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Thanks to @brod