# Rails Models: Does the order of has_many, validation rules matter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Curious about Rails models - in Hartl's Rails Tutorial, he has a User model that includes the following `has_many :microposts
 attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
 before_save :downcase_email
 before_create :create_activation_digest
 has_secure_password`

My question is - does the order you put these in matter?

Answer (score 0):

No not all. You can declare these in anyone set of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not necessary that validations follow any specific order. But you should keep your every validation flexible so that even if presence/length validation fails on any parameter, manipulation over it doesn't throw an error.
You can refer to this answer
            [Controlling the order of rails validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966055/controlling-the-order-of-rails-validations)